# Nginx reverse proxy docker containers LAN

Tags: docker, nginx, localhost

I cannot grasp how nginx reverse proxy works maybe someone can help. Lets say my server with docker in LAN has IP 192.168.0.3 I have such docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

  angular-on-nginx:
    build: angular_client
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./angular_client/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./angular_client/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  express:
    build: express_server
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - ./express_server/:/usr/src/app 
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27777:27777"
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb_data:/data/db
```

On the angular-on-nginx container there is angular app and nginx with such configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /express {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.3:4000/;
    }   
}
```

but this does not work when typing 192.168.0.3 angular web app loads just fine and works. When typing 192.168.0.3:4444 express server gives response just fine but when typing 192.168.0.3/express there is 502 bad gateway. How to make it works so that when I enter 192.168.0.3/express I will get the same result as when typing 192.168.0.3:4444 ?

Comment: server_name  localhost;  I assume you are running nginx as a docker container. So localhost basically means pointing to the same docker container and hence when you add IP, it points outside of docker container it  works for you.
Check this link http://www.littlebigextra.com/install-nginx-reverse-proxy-server-docker/

Answer (score 0):

No idea why but this worked.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  192.168.0.3;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /express/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.3:4444;
    }   
}
```